# PIC16F84A wont run my program on a breadboard

Tags: pic, breadboard

I have written a program on the PIC16F84A and it seems to work perfectly on the PIC testing board. After i had created the program and assembled it onto the PIC, i placed it onto the breadboard and connected all of the inputs and outputs and power lines.

I am using a 2.2 Kohm resistor and a 23 pico farad capacitor for my oscillator values. i have also connected MCLR to V+ WITHOUT a resistor. The rest of my connections are perfect.

However, when i press the push switch to add an input there is no output onto my LED.Do you know if there is a problem with my MCLR connection or is my oscillator speed the fault here or is it something else?

I have tested the program repeatedly to make sure the chip is not damaged or the program is wrong.

[image]

Comment: Does it work on internal oscillator?

Comment: You should add a schematic and your code, from your specs alone it is hard to nail down the problem.

Comment: i have not tried the internal oscillator, i dont really know how to do that. I have been told to use the resistor and the capacitor.

Comment: i dont believe the code is wrong as the code works perfectly on the PIC testing board. i thought it could be the oscillator or the MCLR connection without the resistor but i could not pin point the issue.

Comment: Schematic and photo?

Comment: @C_Elegans PIC16F84A is an ancient chip and does not have an internal RC oscillator. It's like a 741- old, expensive and there is no reason to be using it in 2018.

Comment: I have to use this chip, its parts of my requirements.

Comment: Bread boarding an MPU is not a good idea to begin with. Ground-bounce is terrible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you've set the configuration word correctly for the RC oscillator. Particularly important if your oscillator configuration differs from the "PIC testing board".

Also, you are well below the recommended minimum resistor of 5K\$\Omega\$ for the RC oscillator. It's likely to not work, especially at low supply voltage. Try it with something like 10K and 100pF and see if it runs (albeit slowly). After you confirm that configuration..

Comment: does there need to be a resistor (10Kohm) for the MCLR pin?

Comment: No, it will work when tied directly to Vdd.

Comment: can you point me as to where i can find the configuration word?

Comment: It's completely described in the datasheet, Section 6.0 *6.0 SPECIAL FEATURES OF THE
CPU*